# How do I check if row exists or not?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

This is my code to display/search a record in a database table. How do I put a validation whether the roecord exists or not? It is searching through the ID of a member. how should I show a message if the record does not exist?

```
 string connectionstring = "Server=Momal-PC\\MOMAL;Database=Project;Trusted_Connection=True;";
 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
 conn.ConnectionString = connectionstring;
 conn.Open();


  SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Members where Number = '" + SearchID.Text + "'", conn);
  DataTable dtStock = new DataTable();

  sda.Fill(dtStock);
  dataGridView1.DataSource = dtStock;

  conn.Close();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if( 0 == dtStock.Rows.Count ) // does not exist
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use like this:

```
If(dtStock.Rows.Count > 0) // If dtStock.Rows.Count == 0 then there is no rows exists.
{
    // Your Logic
}
```

See [Here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datatable) & [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.rows.aspx). How to use `Dataset` and `DataTables.`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`DataRowCollection.Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135388.aspx) property.

> Gets the total number of DataRow objects in this collection.

```
If(0 == dtStock.Rows.Count)
  Console.WriteLine("There are no rows in that datatable")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```
    If(dtStock.Rows.Count > 0) 
    {
    //code goes here
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dtStock;
    }
    else
    {
    //Record not exists
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This SQL will be likely be much faster, as it will only return 0 or 1 rows to the client, rather than every matching row and every single column. Get out of the habit of using *

```
SELECT  1 As X WHERE EXISTS (
    Select 1 from Members where Number = '" + SearchID.Text + "')"
```

Comment: Okay. I shall do this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static int RowCount()
        {

            string sqlConnectionString = @" Your connection string";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) AS Expr1 FROM Tablename", con);
            int result = ((int)cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            con.Close();
            return result;
    }
```